# Tycho: generate proguard/obfuscated feature

Tags: proguard, tycho

I have a working tycho build that does:

- build a set of bundles, for each of them:

  - build a regular bundle.jar
  - build/attach a source jar (using the tycho-source-plugin)
  - build an obfuscated jar (using proguard-maven-plugin (com.github.wvengen))
- build a number of features, for each of them:

  - build a regular feature.jar
  - build a source-feature.jar (using tycho-extras:tycho-source-feature)
- build a p2-repository (category.xml references the features and the source-features)
- build/materialize a product (product file references the features)

I didn't find a way yet to create features that use the obfuscated bundle-jars.
With the tycho-source-feature-plugin it is easy to create the corresponding source-features.jars from the source-bundle.jars. Is there an easy possibility to create features that use the obfuscated bundle.jars?

*Visual explanation:*
My workspace looks somewhat like this:

```
com.company.moduleA/
   + /target/com.company.moduleA-1.20.2.jar
   + /target/com.company.moduleA-1.20.2-obfuscated.jar
   + /target/com.company.moduleA-1.20.2-sources.jar
com.company.moduleB/
   + /target/com.company.moduleB-1.20.2.jar
   + /target/com.company.moduleB-1.20.2-obfuscated.jar
   + /target/com.company.moduleB-1.20.2-sources.jar
com.company.featureX/
   + target/com.company.featureX-1.20.2.jar
   + target/com.company.featureX-1.20.2-sources-feature.jar
```

What I'm missing is a way to generate this jar:
   **`+ target/com.company.featureX-1.20.2-obfuscated-feature.jar`**

Edit:
while analyzing my problem I found that the *obfuscated.jars (plugin) are actually deployed, but **not** listed in the modules metadata (p2artifacts.xml) unlike the *sources.jars which are listed in p2artifacts.xml.
I assume this is a problem with the proguard-maven-plugin or with the order/phases I configured the corresponding tycho-plugins. 
Any hints are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many different configuration attempts I ditched the idea of building obfuscated AND non-obfuscated plugins, features and products in just one pass.
I didn't find anyone or any project doing that.

Instead I changed my tycho/maven configuration to obfuscate everything or nothing, using the same artifact-ids and names, but different repositories for deployments (i.e. there's an "obfuscated" repository and a "non-obfuscated" repository).
Switching is done via maven profiles and a command line flag.